# Unicode: convert Javascript escape unicode to Python escape unicode

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, unicode, emoji

The unicode of *thumbs up*  is escaped as `\ud83d\udc4d` and `\U0001f44d` in Javascript and Python separately (reference: http://www.charbase.com/1f44d-unicode-thumbs-up-sign)

Here's the scenario:

I receive  as `\ud83d\udc4d` from the front-end, and now I want to print it out at the server-side, how can I achieve that?

```
>>> print('\ud83d\udc4d')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud83d' in position 0: surrogates not allowed

>>> print('\U0001f44d')
```

To be more precise, I want to save the data into MongoDB by using `pymongo`

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> MongoClient().db.collection.insert({'thumbs_up': '\ud83d\udc4d'})
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud83d' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

However, everything works fine if I convert it into `\U0001f44d`

Comment: How are you scraping this data? Just treat it as *JSON*, if at all possible. Otherwise, see the duplicate.

Comment: The escape you've listed from JavaScript is UTF-16; the Unicode consortium [publish the algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-3) for getting from there to the code unit.